# Using Loop to replace each row in a column in a dataframe wtih the instance that it appears

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a single column in my dataframe called 'data'. I am trying to replace each value using a For Loop with the number of the first instance it appears. For example

```
BatchID   ->   BatchID
Lot 11           1
Lot 11           1
Lot 11           1
Lot 11           1
Lot 12           2
Lot 12           2
Lot 13           3
Lot 14           4
Lot 14           4
Lot 14           4
```

Here is my code:

```
unique_batches = ['Lot 11', 'Lot 12', 'Lot 13', 'Lot 14']

for i in range(len(data['BatchID'])):
    for batch in unique_batches:
        if data['BatchID'][i][:6] == batch:
            data['BatchID'][i] = unique_batches.index(batch) + 1
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
---> 69         if data['BatchID'][i][:10] == batch:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slicing is not needed here

`batches = ['Lot 11', 'Lot 12', 'Lot 13', 'Lot 14']`

Here is the refined code

```
for i in range(len(df['BatchId'])):
    for batch in batches:
        if df["BatchId"][i]==batch:
            df["BatchId"][i] = batches.index(batch)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replace function as well.

Here's an example of how to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'BatchID':['Lot 11','Lot 11','Lot 11','Think1','Lot 12',
                              'Lot 12','Lot 13','Lot 14','Lot 14','Lot 14']})


df = df.replace(r'Lot 1','',regex=True)
print(df)
```

The result will be as follows:

Note that one of the value is `Think1`. So it did not get replaced as it did not meet the pattern.

```
  BatchID
0       1
1       1
2       1
3  Think1
4       2
5       2
6       3
7       4
8       4
9       4
```